# How to rotate a view that is already moving with core animation?

Tags: view, path, rotation, while-loop

I use core animation (CAKeyframeAnimation) to move a view using a given path and at the same time to display the path (dotted line).
While animating the view along the given path i want it to face the direction it is going to.
In other words i want the view to rotate progressively while moving.

After some research i find out it may be possible to do it with CAKeyFrameAnimation using keytimes and values but no success. I have no idea on how to implement it.

As i am still new in IOS programming, i don't know if there is another (better?) way to do such kind of animation.

Here is the code i use:

```
- (CGMutablePathRef) getPathFromPoints:(NSMutableArray*)points {
        CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPoint p = [points[0] CGPointValue];
        CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, p.x, p.y);
        for (int i = 1; i < points.count; ++i) {
            p = [points[i] CGPointValue];
            CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, NULL, p.x, p.y);
        }
        return path;
    }

    - (void)animateView:(UIView*)view
             withPoints:(NSMutableArray*)points
           withFillMode:(NSString*)fillMode
           withDuration:(int)duration
        withRepeatCount:(int)repeat
              withSpeed:(int)speed
             withDashed:(BOOL)dashed{

        CGMutablePathRef path = [self getPathFromPoints:points];

        if (dashed) {
            CAShapeLayer* pathLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
            pathLayer.frame = view.superview.layer.bounds;
            pathLayer.bounds = view.superview.layer.bounds;
            pathLayer.geometryFlipped = NO;
            pathLayer.path = path;
            pathLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
            pathLayer.fillColor = nil;
            pathLayer.lineWidth = 10.0f;
            pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel;
            [pathLayer setLineDashPattern:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:15],
                                           [NSNumber numberWithInt:15],
                                           nil]];
            [view.superview.layer addSublayer:pathLayer];

            CABasicAnimation *dottedAnimation = [CABasicAnimation     animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
            dottedAnimation.duration = duration;
            dottedAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
            dottedAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
            [pathLayer addAnimation:dottedAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];

            [view.superview bringSubviewToFront:view];
        }

        CAKeyframeAnimation* pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        pathAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
        pathAnimation.fillMode = fillMode;
        pathAnimation.duration =  duration;
        pathAnimation.repeatCount = repeat;
        pathAnimation.speed = speed;
        pathAnimation.path = path;
        [view.layer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:_myAnimationKey];
        CGPoint p = [[points lastObject] CGPointValue];
        view.layer.position = CGPointMake(p.x, p.y);
    }
```

Thank you in advance for you help,

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at CAKeyframeAnimation's rotationMode property.  That should accomplish exactly what you are hoping to do.

Add this line to the -animateView: method where the properties for the *pathAnimation CAKeyframeAnimation instance are being set:

pathAnimation.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto;

There's also another setting value, kCAAnimationRotateAutoReverse, that allows the animated object to maintain an anti-parallel orientation with respect to the path tangent.

Link to Apple docs: [CAKeyframeAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: You might want to add an example or additional explanations.